# ssms copy database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a local sql express server with DB A and remote server uXXX.mssql.domainname.com with DB B.

using sql mangament studio 2008, I want to move copy DB A to DB B with all tables, data,  dependencies and stored procedures.

how to figure out this problem? I only had understood table and table data copying(using Tasks->Import Data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the Copy Database Wizard**

In SQL Server Management Studio, go to the **Object Explorer**, expand the list of Databases, right-click your database "B", and in the pop-up menu expand **Tasks**, and then click **Copy Database**, choose your destination server, and you're home!

Comment: Strange, but in object explorer in popup "Tasks" one server have copy database item, but other have not(it was the motiv of the question:)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it may depend on your permissions on that db

Comment: The Copy Database option is not available on Express versions, that might be the issue.