# How to copy database in ssms Express version

Tags: ssms

I just now joined my first job (two days ago) and I am using Microsoft sql server management studio express version here. I want to create a new database by copying data, indexes and all properties from production database(We don't have a QA database) so that I can practice on it. How can I do that. I tried by taking backup of prod db and importing it into new database but it didn't worked and I got this error:

[image].

I am using Express version so no copy database option.

[image]

This might be a possible duplicate of this question: [ssms copy database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744290/ssms-copy-database) but I am using express version.

Can somebody tell me how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not hard to do in SSMS when working with SQLEXPRESS databases. I just executed these steps myself to verify that it works.

1. Create a full backup of the database you want to duplicate. To do this, right click on the database you want to duplicate, select **Tasks**, then **Back Up ...**. Accept the defaults (or alter them if you wish) and click the "OK" button.
2. Now we will restore this backup to a new database. In SSMS, right click on the **Databases** folder icon. Choose **Restore Database ...**. In the **To database:** text box, give your new database a name. I used "test". The name should not duplicate the name of any existing database. In the **From database:** dropdown, select the backup you created in Step 1. Click the "OK" button.

You should now have a copy of your original database, and it is named "test". To see it you may need to right click on the Databases folder icon and choose **Refresh**.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Marty :) It worked. I don't know why I got -ve vote for this question. I didn't find this information on google and that's why I posted it on stackoverflow.

Again Thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure @Novice. I learned something new in researching your answer. So we both win.

Comment: For anyone who might run into the same issues as I did: I am using MSSMS 2012 and I when restoring, I had to manually enter different *file* names (in the second tab on the left of the restoration wizard window), when only a different *database* name was entered, MSSMS attempted to restore the new database to the original files where the back-up'd database resides (and those were luckily locked as it was running). I haven't figured out why this happens, but it's something I was stuck on and hopefully it'll help anyone.